# How to assign classes to all elements?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, functions, comments, post-class

Is it possible to assign classes to elements of certain type?
For example, all paragraphs in the post body or comment body should have class="paragraph", all unordered lists in post body should have class="list", and so on.

Comment: it seems it would be easier to simply target all p or ul tags that are [descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) of whatever container holds the post or comment, then you wouldn't have to add anything. like `.post-container p` or `.comment-container p`.

Comment: Yep, it will be much more easier to do this way. But I need exactly what I've described

Comment: and why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery solution:

**assuming your posts are in a division with the class of "post".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $(".post p").each(function(){ 
      $(this).addClass('paragraph'); 
       });
      $(".post ul").each(function(){ 
      $(this).addClass('list'); 
       });
      //add more lines here to select more elements
    });
</script>
```

Paste this in your footer.

*you need jquery installed. And better yet would be to enque this using http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: thanks, but I need to do it inside wordpress, not with js

Comment: Do you mean you need to accomplish this using php? You could use `apply_filter( 'the_content', 'your_filter_function');` and have `your_filter_functions` replace the html elements with the same elements but with your desired classes.